# Remove semicolons from list items

Tags: c#, generic-list

I have a list that contans various string records. Some of the records consists of various sub-records that are seperated by semicolons. For example as follows

> Life Skills
>
> No Related Topics
>
> Communication
>
> Careers; Listening Skills; Personal Development; Questioning Skills; Coaching/Mentoring;
>    Recognition; Recruitment and Selection.
>
> Customer Service
>
> Physical Education

What I want to do now is to **iterate through the records seperate all the records that contains the semicolon** and **make sure there are no duplicates**.

```
for(int i=0; i<lst.Count; i++) {
    // seperate the records that contains ';' into individual unique items
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What do you want to do with the sub records once you've separated them out?

Comment: Yeah that's a very important element to consider, I wrote my answer not knowing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
        List<String> lst = new List<string>();
        lst.Add("Life Skills");
        lst.Add("Life Skills");
        lst.Add("Communication");
        lst.Add("Careers; Listening Skills;Life Skills; Personal Development; Questioning Skills; Coaching/Mentoring; Recognition; Recruitment and Selection.");
        lst.Add("No Related Topics");

        List<string> newList = new List<string>();

        foreach (string str in lst)
        {
            var temp = str.Split(';');
            if (temp.Length > 1)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < temp.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (!newList.Contains(temp[i]))
                    {
                        newList.Add(temp[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (!newList.Contains(str))
                {
                    newList.Add(str);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linq to implement it

```
lst = lst
  .SelectMany(i => string.Split(";", i))
  .Select(i => i.Trim())
  .Distinct()
  .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to implement some kind of parser for your program. StackOverflow isn't going to write your programs for you but I suggest looking into http://boost-spirit.com/home/

If you choose to roll your own, perhaps for licensing reasons, loading your text input, perhaps loading the result into a buffer until a semicolon is reached, then copying the buffer to a string and pushing it into an array would be ideal. From there you could keep looping until you reach the end of the file.